# Can pynput be used with variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

What im trying to accomplish is that x would be set to a number and after a loop with start and after the end of a loop x would be +1. but i cant get pynput to type integers. is there anyway i could use pynput to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please do _not_ paste images of code or links to such images. Paste the actual formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast x to a string in the function call. For example,

```
for x in range(15):
    keyboard.type(str(x))
```